# allow simple quote and double quote in regex

Tags: regex

I've got this regex `/src='cid:(.*)'/Uims` and it works fine but only match element in single quote . What is the way to also allow result who match double quotes (like `/src="cid:(.*)"/Uims`) but in a single regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/src=(["'])cid:(.*?)\1/Uims
```

Store the type of quotation as a back reference and refer to it where it should be closed.
Note that the back reference you are using will be located at \2 (or $2) instead of \1.

Oh, and you probably want to make the grouping lazy (non-greedy), so I added a `?` after `.*`. See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
...'\''...
```

on each occurrence of single quote.